# I'm trying to create a function that will randomly choose a dictionary value instead of a key

Tags: python

I have a function for calling random key from a dictionary but and figure out how to edit it to select a random value instead.

```
def show_definition():
    random_definition = choice(list.values(glossary))
```

I now have this i want to print the key that corresponds to the value.

```
def show_definition():
    random_definition = choice(list(glossary.values()))
    print('What word is being defined?: ', random_definition)
    input('Press return to see the ')
    print(glossary[random_definition])
```

Comment: random_key = choice(list(glossary)) this is what I had for the random key which worked fine

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. You might have seen that your question has been getting many answers, but also many downvotes. This is because it's a relatively simple one, so many people want to help you out, but it's also not very clearly posted - in the future, when you want to ask more complicated questions, it'll be good to learn how to ask a good question - see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: Your latest edit to the question was already answered by @NoufalIbrahim over 20 minutes ago.

Comment: well I don't understand how to incorporate his answer into my code I fairly new to python so my understanding is limited.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.

**Python 2:**

```
choice(glossary.values())
```

**Python 3:**

```
choice(list(glossary.values()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just choose a key, value pair directly like so

```
>>> import random
>>> d = dict(x=1, y=2, z=3)
>>> random.choice(list(d.items()))
('x', 1)
>>> random.choice(list(d.items()))
('z', 3)
>>> random.choice(list(d.items()))
('y', 2)
>>> random.choice(list(d.items()))
('x', 1)
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it to select values instead of keys, or both?
If both - Noufal Ibrahim's answer works.
If only value - you can call `.values()` instead of `.items()`:

```
from random import choice

example = {'a':1, 'b':2}
choice(list(example.values()))
```

Comment: I want to show the definition first then, after a key is pressed show the key

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
import random
    weight_dict = {
      1:"A",
      2:"B",
      3:"C"
    }
    def show_rand():
        key = random.choice(list(weight_dict))
        print ("Random key value pair from dictonary is ", key, " - ", weight_dict[key])
    show_rand()
```

Comment: It does the selection inside the print, unlike what OP requested.